# Transaction rollback Error object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to show error message which we get in a process of transaction. 
This is my student.rb (model)

```
def self.createStudent (user , student , father , mother)
    begin
      transaction do
        father.save!
        mother.save!
        user.save!
        student.mother=mother
        student.father=father
        student.user=user
        student.save
      end
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => invalid
      return 
    end
  end
```

And this method is called from a controller

```
Student.createStudent(@user,@student,@father,@mother)
```

Now I want to check again in controller that upon saving is their any error or not . And send back to view

Comment: in what event do you want to rollback ? look at this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Rollback.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return values from this method, both when it succeeds or when it fails.

```
def self.createStudent (user , student , father , mother)
  begin
    transaction do
      father.save!
      mother.save!
      user.save!
      student.mother=mother
      student.father=father
      student.user=user
      student.save
    end 
    return "success"
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => invalid
    return invalid.record.errors
  end
end
```

Now in your controller you can check for the return value and show the message in view based on the return value.

**EDIT** (based on your comment):

`invalid.record.errors` will have the error on which the transaction failed.

Check the [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/RecordInvalid.html).

Comment: but I want to show error message that provide by rails like email is already taken

Comment: @abhaygarg12493 You need to create methods to check for conditions(like email is already taken) and return a message along with the boolean flag from this method maybe?

Comment: I think rails should provide any better way, we have around 3,4 constraints

Comment: Check my edited answer. I think you are looking for `invalid.record.errors`